# Replace the regex search term with the new character along with the regex term

Tags: substitute

Consider the following text:

```
alpha0_inc0 : beta0_inc0_term
alpha1_inc1 : beta1_inc1_term
alpha2_inc2 : beta2_inc1_term
alpha3_inc3 : beta3_inc0_term
```

I want to replace text matching the regex `inc\d` with the `match+new`. The expected result should be:

```
alpha0_inc0_new : beta0_inc0_new_term
alpha1_inc1_new : beta1_inc1_new_term
alpha2_inc2_new : beta2_inc1_new_term
alpha3_inc3_new : beta3_inc0_new_term
```

`inc\d` matches `inc0`, `inc1`, etc. The issue is I want to just add a new term to all the regex matches.

One way to do this would be to use:

```
:%s/inc0/inc0_new/g
:%s/inc1/inc1_new/g
:%s/inc2/inc2_new/g
:%s/inc3/inc3_new/g
```

But this gets tedious quickly. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` in your replacement string, which replaces the whole match, so you can easily add to it.

```
:%s/inc\d/&_new/g
```

See [`:help :s&`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As%25) for more special sequences you can use in substitutions.

In particular, if you want to use parts of the match, you can group parts with pairs of `\(` and `\)` and refer back to them with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Finally, for most flexibility, you can use [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) which allows you to enter an expression and use VimL to generate your replacement string.